# как найти значение в словаре(хеш-таблице)?

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DictionaryPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // English to Russian Dictionary
    Map<String,String> engRus = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //добавление элементов
    engRus.put("Monday", "Понедельник");
    engRus.put("Tuesday", "Вторник");
    engRus.put("Wednesday", "Среда");
    engRus.put("Thursday", "Четверг");
    engRus.put("Friday", "Пятница");
```

А как мне осуществлять поиск среди них,например я ввожу monday,а на выход получаю "понедельник"?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, то  плюсаните его, нажав на стрелку вверх рядом с ним, а если решил вашу проблему - примите его, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


class DictionaryPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // English to Russian Dictionary
        Map<String,String> engRus = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //добавление элементов
        engRus.put("Monday", "Понедельник");
        engRus.put("Tuesday", "Вторник");
        engRus.put("Wednesday", "Среда");
        engRus.put("Thursday", "Четверг");
        engRus.put("Friday", "Пятница");

        String day = "";
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            day = scan.next();
            // при вводе stop выходим из программы
            if(day.equals("stop")){
                break;
            }
            String rus = engRus.get(day);
            System.out.println("Результат: " + rus);
        }
     }
}
```